# Python Code not working correctly

Tags: python

Hi this is my second post on this code I dont get errors but the if else statement is not working how I want the if(calculate[2] == opperations:
code is not working, it wont register even if i have a - or + there. Any ideas why? It gives me the response Sorry invalid text3.

```
calculate = input("Enter the problem in the format x + y = z ")

opperations = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
space = " "
a = calculate[0]
a = int(a)
b = calculate[4]
b = int(b)

def opperation():
if opperations == "+":
    A = 1
elif opperations == "-":
    A = 2
elif opperations == "*":
    A = 3
elif opperations == "/":
    A = 4

if calculate[0] in numbers:
    if len(calculate) > 1:
        if calculate[2] == opperations:
            if calculate[1] == space:
                if A == 1:
                    c = a + b
                    print (c)
                elif A == 2:
                    c = a - b
                    print (c)
                elif A == 3:
                    c = a * b
                    print(c)
                elif A == 4:
                    c = a / b
                    print(c)
                else:
                    print("Sorry invalid text5")
            else:
                print("Sorry invalid text4")
        else:
            print("Sorry invalid text3")
    else:
        print("Sorry invalid text2")
else:
    print("Sorry invalid text1")
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want to use `calculate[2] in opperations` instead of what you currently have.

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

The condition

```
if calculate[2] == opperations:
```

will compare `calculate[2]` with the whole list `["+", "-", "*", "/"]`. You can instead use the `in` keyword, to check if a element is inside a sequence:

```
if calculate[2] in opperations:
    # ...
```

**Also**, in the part where you compare `opperations` with `"+"`, `"-` ... You should be comparing them with `calculate[2]`:

```
if calculate[2] == "+":
    A = 1
elif calculate[2] == "-":
    A = 2
elif calculate[2] == "*":
    A = 3
elif calculate[2] == "/":
    A = 4
```

**Notes:** Your approach will just handle operations with `1` digit numbers. I would recommend you to use the `split(" ")` method so you can use it like:

```
s = "100 + 20"
parts = s.split(" ")   # split by space
parts[0] # 100
parts[1] # +
parts[2] # 20
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Christian's suggestions, the `if` `elif` chain could be replaced by a dictionary lookup. In this example `lambda a, b: a+b` is a function that takes two values `a` and `b` and return there sum. That means `opperations["+"]` returns a function and `opperations["+"](a,b)` returns the sum of `a` and `b`.

```
opperations = { "+": lambda a, b: a+b, 
               "-": lambda a, b: a-b,
               "*": lambda a, b: a*b,
               "/": lambda a, b: a/b }

calculate = raw_input("Enter the problem in the format x + y = z ")

numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
space = " "
a = calculate[0]
a = int(a)
b = calculate[4]
b = int(b)

if calculate[0] in numbers:
    if len(calculate) > 1:
        if calculate[2] in opperations:
            if calculate[1] == space:
                c = opperations[calculate[2]](a,b)
                print (c)
            else:
                print("Sorry invalid text4")
        else:
            print("Sorry invalid text3")
    else:
        print("Sorry invalid text2")
else:
    print("Sorry invalid text1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to make a new python file and then create a function in it and then import it:

```
def calculate(calculation):
    with open('calculation_file', 'w') as FILE:
        FILE.write(
        '''
        def calculate():
            return ''' + calculation + '''
        ''')
    import calculation_file as c
    return c.calculate
```

it creates a file and then imports it and returns what the calculation_file
`There are probably some bugs though because I have not run it yet`
also you probably need to make the variables `a`, `b` an intager with `int(a)`